# the present tense referring to the future in subordinate clauses

Tags: present-tense

"If she breaks that wall, she will have to pay."
"Go to the first man that rings the bell."

I know that the sentences above are correct in the present tense of the subordinate clauses. but I'm not sure about the tenses in the subordinate clauses below.

"We have gotten an opportunity that we will borrow a gym for a day."
"He will tell you that he is working on a science project, which he will start tomorrow."

Can you tell me exactly when to use the present tense in subordinate clauses whose main clause refers to the future to refer to the future? I want to know all the cases. (And I want to get many answers.)

Answer (score 0):

The tenses do not need to match, eg your first sentence "If she breaks that wall, she will have to pay" has present and future. However the sentence

> ```
> We have gotten an opportunity that we will borrow a gym for a day.
> ```

seems very awkward to me. It is not the tenses though; it is because "opportunity that" makes me look for a verb with the opportunity as its subject.

> ```
> We have gotten an opportunity that will let us borrow a gym for a day
> ```

solves this. The tenses of "have gotten" in the past and "will let" in the future do not match and it is fine.

> ```
> He will tell you that he is working on a science project, which he will start tomorrow
> ```

has future, present and future. The sentence is fine, but if "he" tells "you" today, he is lying because he will not have started until tomorrow.